# Question about Riemann integral and total variation

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $g$ be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, $f(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt$ for $x∈[a,b]$.

How to show that the total variation of $f$ is equal to $∫_a^b|g(x)|dx$?

Comment: I think it's good to mention that this is also posted on Math SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150579/question-about-riemann-integral-and-total-variation

Comment: But all the Answers on SE have bug.